# The fundamental group of $S^3 \setminus (\text{Hopf link})$ is $\mathbb{Z}^2$.

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, fundamental-groups, retraction

Here $S^3$ is the $3$-sphere, and the Hopf link is described as in [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hopf_link).

In my class, we have done work to show that $S^3 \setminus (\text{Hopf link}) \cong \mathbb{R} \times T^2$, where $T^2$ is the usual torus. For the purpose of this question I will just treat this as given. The note goes on to say that $\mathbb{R} \times T^2$ is homotopically equivalent to $T^2$, hence we can make the inference that $\pi_1(S^3 \setminus (\text{Hopf link})) \cong \pi_1(T^2) \cong \mathbb{Z}^2$.

I have two questions about this last claim.

1. I want to make sure I understand the homotopy equivalence mentioned. If we see $\mathbb{R} \times T^2$ as living in $\mathbb{R}^5$ (i.e. consisting of $5$-tuple points), can we see the retraction as resulted from “removing” the first coordinates?
2. I see how we can have $\pi_1(S^3 \setminus (\text{Hopf link})) \cong \pi_1(\mathbb{R} \times T^2)$, as fundamental groups of homeomorphic spaces are isomorphic. But what about the second inference? Are fundamental groups of homotopically equivalent spaces also isomorphic?

Comment: A retraction from $X$ to $Y$ can be extended to one from $X\times Z$ to $Y\times Z$. This applies here with $X=\Bbb R,Y=\{{\rm pt}\},Z=T^2$.  And yes, spaces that are homotopy equivalent have the same homotopy groups, yes. Also we have $\pi_1(A\times B)\cong\pi_1(A)\times\pi_2(B)$, which applies here for $A=\Bbb R,B=T^2$.

Comment: I’ve worked out the proof for the second claim. But is there an intuitive explanation (or picture) on why it is true?

Comment: I would consider the explanation a categorical one: any map $S^1\to A\times B$ is equivalent to two maps $S^1\to A$ and $S^1\to B$.